# How to set the StringFormat for specific columns in a WPF Datagrid whose values are populated via ItemsSource method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid whose values are populated via ItemsSource method.

How would I go about doing something similar to the code below so that it's formatted decently? Also would there be a way to simply carry over the StringFormat's from the Source table?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=d}" Header="Date" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat=C}" Header="Amount"/>
```

The table is generated through this code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datatable" ItemsSource="{Binding SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl}"/>
```

Comment: When you say, "whose values are populated", do you mean the _columns_ are being automatically populated?

Comment: columns and rows. Everything. I'll post the code that generates the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is to use AutoGeneratingColumn

```
private void datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridTextColumn col = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    if (col != null && e.PropertyType == typeof(double))
    {
        if (!col.Header.ToString() == "Amount")
            col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "N0" };
        else
            col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "N2" };
    }
}
```

Also you can define the format you want for each col by checking the col.Header.ToString()

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the *columns* are being automatically populated, I would suggest creating an attached behavior that subscribes to the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event, inspects the property being bound, and assigns a default format.

You could look for `[DataType]` attributes for hints and, if you don't find any, pick a sensible default based on the column's data type:

```cs
// #using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
// #using System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

public class AutoColumnFormatBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn += OnAutoGeneratingColumn;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.AutoGeneratingColumn -= OnAutoGeneratingColumn;
    }

    private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(
        object sender,
        DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = (e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn)?.Binding;
        if (binding != null && binding.StringFormat == null)
            binding.StringFormat = GetFormat(e.PropertyType, e.PropertyDescriptor);
    }

    private static string GetFormat(Type type, object descriptor)
    {
        var attribute = default(DataTypeAttribute);

        if (descriptor is MemberInfo mi)
            attribute = mi.GetCustomAttribute<DataTypeAttribute>();
        else if (descriptor is MemberDescriptor md)
            attribute = md.Attributes[typeof(DataTypeAttribute)] as DataTypeAttribute;

        var typeCode = GetTypeCode(type);
        var isNumericType = typeCode >= TypeCode.SByte && typeCode <= TypeCode.Decimal;
        var isIntegerType = isNumericType && typeCode < TypeCode.Single;

        if (attribute?.DataType == DataType.Currency)
            return isIntegerType ? "C0" : "C";

        var formatFromAttribute = attribute?.DisplayFormat?.DataFormatString;
        if (formatFromAttribute != null)
            return formatFromAttribute;

        if (isNumericType)
            return isIntegerType ? "N0" : "N";

        return null;
    }

    private static TypeCode GetTypeCode(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            type = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        if (type.IsEnum)
            return TypeCode.Object;
        return Type.GetTypeCode(type);
    }
}
```

Here's the behavior attached to a `DataGrid` with some sample data:

```xml
<DataGrid xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
          xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfTest">

  <!-- Attach the behavior: -->
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <l:AutoColumnFormatBehavior />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

  <!-- Add some sample data: -->
  <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="l:SampleItem">
      <l:SampleItem RealMoney="1234.5678"
                    RealValue="1234.5678"
                    IntMoney="1234"
                    IntValue="1234"
                    Date="{x:Static s:DateTime.Now}"
                    Time="{x:Static s:DateTime.Now}"
                    DateTime="{x:Static s:DateTime.Now}" />
    </x:Array>
  </DataGrid.ItemsSource>

</DataGrid>
```

Here's the class I used for the row items:

```cs
public class SampleItem
{
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double RealMoney { get; set; }

    public double RealValue { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public int IntMoney { get; set; }

    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And here's a screenshot showing the results:

[image: Screenshot]