# WPF: How to handle null values in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, behavior

I am a "fresh" WPF developer (I started 3 month ago), so this may be relative easy to solve for an expert (I hope so!)

I have create a view which summaries the processing results. For a better overview, all is packed into a DataGrid.

I am also using a custom Behavior to auto format the table content according to column data type base on [How to set the StringFormat for specific columns in a WPF Datagrid whose values are populated via ItemsSource method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451247/how-to-set-the-stringformat-for-specific-columns-in-a-wpf-datagrid-whose-values)

All works fine as long as all cells contains a non null value. When a cell is empty or filled with `DBNull.Value`, following exception is generated: `property not found on object of type DataRowView`

The `DataTable` is generated by code (C#), something like this:

```
ValueTable = new DataTable("DataTable");

// add timeline
DataColumn dtColumn = new DataColumn
                    {
                        DataType = typeof(double),
                        ColumnName = DefaultColumnName,
                        Caption = DefaultColumnName,
                        ReadOnly = true,
                        Unique = true
                    };
ValueTable.Columns.Add(dtColumn);
ValueTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ValueTable.Columns[DefaultColumnName] };
foreach(var col in MyData)
{
    dtColumn = new DataColumn
    {
        DataType = typeof(double),
        ColumnName = col.Name,
        Caption = col.Name,
        ReadOnly = true,
        Unique = false,
        AllowDBNull= true
    };
    ValueTable.Columns.Add(dtColumn);
}

...
// fill the columns
foreach(double currentTimein TimeLine)
{
    DataRow myDataRow = ValueTable.NewRow();
    myDataRow[DefaultColumnName] = currentTime;
    foreach(var col in MyData)
    {
        myDataRow[col.Name] = col.HasDataFor(currentTime) ? col.GetValue(currentTime) : DBNull.Value;
    }
    ValueTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
}
```

And on WPF side:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ValueTable}" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" IsReadOnly="True">
    <!-- Attach the behavior for autoformating the float values -->
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <l:AutoColumnFormatBehavior FloatFormat="0.#####"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

Note: removing the attached Behavior don't change anything.

**Note2**: when a row contains a null value, the hole row is showed as empty, but on copy/past all values are copied!

Any suggestion?

Regards

Comment: My first suggestion would be not to auto generate columns in a datagrid. Why are you doing that if you want specific formatting?  Why is this a datatable rather than a observablecollection<t>  where t is a viewmodel?
I'd also think twice about editing directly in a datagrid.
It's ok if you can use behaviours / combobox etc to force valid input.  If you have any validation at all though, it's usually a nuisance.

Comment: @Andy: the columns are auto generated because the number depends on what kind of process has been done. In fact, `ValueTable` is a member of the viewmodel. I tried to extract only the relevant part of my code.

Comment: @Andy: The goal is to show a summary of all tests results and to be able to copy them (and past to an excel sheet for example).

As written, the copy/past to excel works, but in the WPF application, rows with empty cells are completely empty and I've got an error message `property not found on object of type DataRowView`.

As I am fairly new to WPF, maybe my way is not correct. I am open to suggestions.